# Jenkins post build task if status changed from "failed" to "success" (fixed)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, post-build

In a Jenkins freestyle job (on an older 1.6x version, no support for 2.x pipeline jobs) I would like to run a shell command (`curl -XPOST ...`) as a post build step if the build status recovered(!) from `FAILED` to `SUCCESS`.

However, all plugins for determining the build status I am aware of can only do something if the current build status IS `FAILED` or `SUCCESS` but don't take into account whether it recovered in comparison to the last build.

Is there any way how to achieve this, e.g. using the `Groovy Post build` plugin and some lines of scripting?

Answer (score 2):

I found that something like this is a good way to go.
You can build up some interesting logic, and the "currentBuild" variable has some decent documentation here: [currentBuild variable doc](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild)

```
    script {
       if ( ( currentBuild.resultIsBetterOrEqualTo("SUCCESS") && currentBuild.previousBuild.resultIsWorseOrEqualTo("UNSTABLE") ) || currentBuild.resultIsWorseOrEqualTo("UNSTABLE")) {
         echo "If current build is good, and last build is bad, or current build is bad"
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found a way to achieve this. It is not necessarily pretty and I still appreciate alternative solutions :)

First of all, a plugin is needed which lets you execute shell commands in a Post Build step. There might be different ones, I am using [the PostBuildScript plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin) for that.

Then, create a "Execute a set of scripts" post build step, set the step to execute to `Build step` and select `Execute shell`, for me this looks like this:
[image: Jenkins post build step]

In there, I run the following shell script lines which use my Jenkins server's REST API in combination with a Python one-liner (you could also use `jq` or something else for this) to determine the status of the current build as well as of the last completed build:

```
statusOfCurrentBuild=$(curl --silent "${BUILD_URL}api/json" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['result']")
statusOfLastBuild=$(curl --silent "${JOB_URL}/lastCompletedBuild/api/json" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['result']")

if [ "${statusOfCurrentBuild}" == "SUCCESS" ] && [ "${statusOfLastBuild}" == "FAILURE" ]
then
    echo "Build was fixed"
    # do something interesting here
fi
```

Depending on your Jenkins settings, using the REST API might require authentication.